# What does Google BigQuery's string "t0" mean?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've trying to understand GoogleBigQuery and I've seen this in a Query : `AS t0`

I also see t0 attached to some metrics or dimension like this `t0.postId`

Here is the full query I'm trying to understand :

```
SELECT t0.Author, COUNT(DISTINCT t0.postId, 50000) AS t0.calc_FPB538 FROM (SELECT
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 10, hits.customDimensions.value,  NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS postId,
  date(MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 4, hits.customDimensions.value,  NULL))) WITHIN RECORD AS Datepublished,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 1, hits.customDimensions.value,  NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Country,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 7, hits.customDimensions.value,  NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Author,
FROM
  [My_data.ga_sessions_20161104]) AS t0 WHERE (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP(STRING(t0.Datepublished))), '%Y%m%d') >= '20161102' AND STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP(STRING(t0.Datepublished))), '%Y%m%d') <= '20161108') GROUP EACH BY t0.Author ORDER BY t0.calc_FPB538 DESC
```

What does it mean, how should I use it ?

Thanks.

Comment: In sql type queries `as` is a way of labeling a table. This is helpful when you have joins so you can specify which column you mean (mostly needed when they have columns with the same name). So you labeled something as t0 and are referencing the datapoint `postId` by that .

Comment: what do you mean by referencing the datapoint ?

Comment: In sql terms `postId` is a column on the table referenced by the label `t0`

Comment: ok... thanks. I've updated my question with the whole query I'm trying to understand. Can you give me a more broader explanation of this query as an answer ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you really need to find a tutorial on basic sql/query terms and methods, but in general (and I'm going to use general terms like object as it applies whether table or not) when you see syntax like this:

```
[My_data.ga_sessions_20161104]) AS t0
```

You are saying look at this object/table `[My_data.ga_session_20161104]` and give it a label of t0 so I can reference columns/datapoints on that object. Then when you later see things like `t0.postId` you know that you are referencing `[My_data.ga_sessions_20161104]`. This way if you reference another similar table that has a datapoint/column of `postId` both you and the engine running the query knows what the heck you are talking about.

You can also label columns/data points as you see in your query with `COUNT(DISTINCT t0.postId, 50000) AS t0.calc_FPB538` this is saying perform a count on the number of `postId` results and label it as `t0.calc_FPB538` because I will want to reference it as such later (or you just like your resutls to have specific names).